# Como insertar una LocalDateTime(Fecha con hora) en una base de datosMySQL

Tags: java, mysql

tengo una base de datos creada con phpMyAdmin, y en una tabla "reservas" tengo un campo que me pide la fecha y hora especifica de una reserva.
Ahora el problema esta en el que al momento de insertar la reserva, no me toma la fecha, cuando yo hago y me sale error:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reserva (nombre, dni, fecha, id_mesa, vigente) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 1)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            LocalDateTime ldt = reserva.getFecha();
            ps.setDate(3, ldt);
```

Tampoco me deja setearlo así

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reserva (nombre, dni, fecha, id_mesa, vigente) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 1)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        LocalDateTime ldt = reserva.getFecha();
        ps.setString(3, ldt.getYear()+"-"+ldt.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+ldt.getDayOfMonth()+" "+ldt.getHour()+":"+ldt.getMinute()+":00");
```

Con los demás datos anda perfecto, ¿Como puedo hacer para pasarle una fecha especifica con hora a la base de datos?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: intenta pasandole como parametro a tu sql: *NOW()*, ´INSERT INTO reserva (nombre, dni, NOW(), id_mesa, vigente) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 1)´

Comment: Si, pero NOW() me devuelve la fecha actual y necesito que sea una fecha en particular, puede ser cualquier fecha

Comment: reserva.getFecha() es el valor que quieres guardar en su statement sql?

Comment: Su añades como valor por defecto el NOW() ni tienes que enviarlo en el insert. Aunque a mi forma de ver un CurrentTime() te amplia las funciones o un TIMESTAMP() te da mas oportunidades.

Comment: reserva.getFecha() si eso quiero agregar a mi sentencia.

Comment: Gracias a todos, no habrá una función SQL, que me permita agregar una fecha con horas y minutos? Asi la concateno directamente a la Sentencia SQL

Comment: No está dos veces: ldt.getDayOfMonth()?

Comment: Si tienes razón, me di cuenta pero ya lo corregí, pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con lo siguiente, espero sea de ayuda:

```
// LocalDateTime fechaEspecifica = LocalDateTime.of(AÑO, MES, DIA, HORA, MINUTO, SEGUNDO);
LocalDateTime fechaEspecifica = LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.JANUARY, 1, 10, 10, 30);
```